# Is it possible to have discontinuities in the phase portrait of a dynamical system? If yes what does it really mean?

Tags: computational-physics, differential-equations, phase-space, software, complex-systems

I've been using Mathematica to draw the phase portrait of a system and I got some jumps along the trajectory. I have a deviation term which might be the reason of this but is it possible to have them or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Phase portraits can't be discontinuous unless the dynamics is discontinuous, since each point of the phase space corresponds to a state. So if the dynamics is expressed through a differential equation there must at least be continuity. Note that trajectories in this case only have to be $C^0$ continuous, the derivatives might be discontinuous producing corners and other oddities.

Comment: My solutions are quite complex to check the discontinuities but I think it may due to the deviation from the harmonic oscillator. Thank you.

Comment: @TheDreamer - What is the system?